# How to write prototype for command "ext_skel"?

Tags: php, pecl

when i develop PECL extension of some function,I could write func.def like follows:

> string return_hello()
>
> string return_name()

then,I run command like follows:

```
./ext_skel --extname=newextension --proto=func.def
```

But I don't know how to write the file func.def above,when i want to develop some  extension class for php. I don't find a whole manual about that.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Extending-Embedding-PHP-Sara-Goleman/dp/B000K7MKQA/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424867790&sr=1-1

Comment: the book is too old for us. and I want to know a function list to be used in my code about php extension.

Comment: That book is still (despite being old and out-of-date) the best documentation that you'll find anywhere

Comment: The alternative is that you look at tools like zephyr or phpcpp to build extensions

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [extSkel](https://github.com/7snovic/extskel), the basic usage is :

```
php extSkel --proto="path/to/file" --extension=extname
```

to define a class proto file you need to define a class with a `$protoType = 'class';`

there are another full examples in the [examples](https://github.com/7snovic/extSkel/blob/master/examples/) directory